# What is this bot in server logs?

Tags: web-crawlers, webserver, logs

Noticed this bot in the top ten bots in the server logs:

```
dwbot
```

Coming from the United States.

Does any one have any idea what it is?

Answer (score 1):

According to a google search, for "dwbot", it must be an old dream world bot for an online Pokemon game.

See: https://github.com/Sanqui/dwbot

Comment: old and dysfunctional ;)

Comment: Yeah I found this, but presumed it wasn't the same bot. Why would some bot for an old Pokemon game be making upwards of 30K requests every day on a website?

There are also similar bots with the same name on Git Hub https://github.com/dwbot/dwbot   I don't think it is these.